# Gradient of a (Lyapunov) function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, control-theory, lyapunov-functions

For $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, define $\hat{r}(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
       \vec{0}     ,& x = 0\\
      \frac{x}{||x||} ,& x \ne0\\
\end{array} 
\right. $

and for some $r>0$, $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$: $$B_r(x_0) = \{x \in \mathbb{R^{n}}: ||x-x_0|| < r \}$$

Consider the differential equation:
$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = f(x(t)),\text{ with } x(0) = k$$ $k \in B_r(0)$ and f is Lipschitz continuous in $B_r(0)$

Does there exist a scalar function $V(x) \in C^{1}$ such that:

1. $\nabla{V}(x) \cdot \hat{r}(x) < 0$, for some $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $||x||\in(0,r)$
2. $\frac{dV(x(t))}{dt} = \nabla{V}(x(t)) \cdot \frac{dx(t)}{dt} = \nabla{V}(x(t)) \cdot f(x(t)) < 0$ for all $x \in B_r(0)-\{0\}$
3. $V(x) > 0$ for all $x \in B_r(0)-\{0\}$
4. $V(0) = 0$

Can you give me an example of a function that satisfies all of the above? 
An example for 2-D vector x would be ok.

Comment: Let $\varphi(\lambda x_0) = V(\lambda x_0)$ for $\lambda \ge 0$ and a given $x_0\not = 0$. By condition 1., $\varphi$ decreases for $\lambda > 0$. By condition 3., $\varphi(\lambda)> 0$ and by condition 4, $\varphi(0)=0$. It is impossible.

Comment: @Gribouillis thank you! The thought process is clear. You probably meant $\phi(\lambda) = V(\lambda x_0)$. Also you imply it is impossible due to continuity @ 0?

Comment: Instead of $x1$ (etc.), write `$x_1$` to get $x_1$.

Comment: @Anonymous yes a continuous function cannot decrease from $0$ and be positive. Where did you get the conditions from?

Comment: @Gribouillis  I borrowed conditions 2-4 from the Lyapunov theorem for stability, and the 1st condition I was trying to prove the opposite, i.e. that $\nabla V(x) \cdot \hat{r}(x) \geq 0$ while trying to understand why the countours here: https://ibb.co/zRyLtwp obey the inequality $c_1 < c_2$, 

more specifically why the gradient always pointed to the outside of the region enclosed by the contours.

Comment: I edited condition 1, so now again it is impossible for such a function to exist. The proof, in short, is $\phi(\lambda) = V(\lambda x_0)$ has positive derivative at least at the neighbourhood of $0$. $\phi^\prime (1) = \nabla V(x_0) \cdot x_0 < 0$ from condition 1. By bolzano's theorem $\exists \lambda_0 \in (\epsilon, 1): \phi^\prime(\lambda_0) = 0 \iff \nabla V(\lambda_0 x_0) = 0$ contradiction by the 2nd condition.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that:

**I.** $||x_0|| \in (0,r)$ and 
**II.** $\nabla{V}(x_0) \cdot \hat{r}(x_0) < 0 \iff \nabla{V}(x_0) \cdot x_0 < 0$

Define $g(\lambda) = V(\lambda x_0)$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ 
$g(\lambda) \in C^1$, thus $$g^\prime(\lambda) = \nabla V(\lambda x_0) \cdot \frac{d(\lambda x_0)}{d\lambda} = \nabla V(\lambda x_0) \cdot x_0$$

$g^\prime(1) = \nabla V(x_0) \cdot x_0 < 0$, due to condition II.

$g(0) = 0$ from condition 4.

Let's apply the Mean Value Theorem for derivatives, for the function $g$ in the interval $[0,1]$

- g is continuous in [0,1]
- g is differentiable in (0,1)

Hence, $\exists \xi \in (0,1):$
$$g^\prime(\xi) = \frac{g(1)-g(0)}{1-0} = g(1) = V(x_0) > 0$$ by condition 3.

Now, let's apply Bolzano's Theorem for $g^\prime$ in $[\xi,1]$:

- $g^\prime$ is continuous in $[\xi,1]$ (since $g \in C^1$)
- $g^\prime(\xi) \cdot g^\prime(1) < 0$

Hence, $\exists \lambda_0 \in (\xi, 1): g^\prime(\lambda_0) = 0 \iff \nabla V(\lambda_0 x_0) \cdot x_0 = 0 \iff \nabla V(\lambda_0 x_0) \perp x_0$

Comment: I made a mistake in the proof, so now it is incomplete :(

Comment: I suspect that if it is really impossible to construct such a function, then every trajectory that solves the differential equation should spiral towards $0$, in such a way that the distance $||x(t)||$ is a strictly decreasing function for all $t \geq 0$. If there is an answer to this problem, then maybe one can answer to the question of this post